# ¿Existe alguna manera de implementar un listener para todos los clicks que se den en una sesión Java?

Tags: java

Como la pregunta lo dice, ¿se podrá crear un `listener` que detecte cada click que se dé en la sesión abierta de Java?. Mi intención es guardarlo en una base de datos para poder reproducir exactamente lo que cada usuario realiza en la sesión, tipo una huella de auditoría.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede guardar cada "click" del usuario en la aplicación web. Lo que se puede es colocar un filtro que se dispare cada vez que el usuario manda un request desde la aplicación.

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class FiltroAplicacion implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }

    //este método se ejecuta antes y después del ciclo request/response
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Obtenemos los objetos de request, response y sesión
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        //a partir de la sesión podemos obtener el usuario y su información
        if (session != null) {
            Usuario usuario = (Usuario)session.getAttribute("usuario");
            //si el usuario existe, es decir, se ha logueado al sistema
            if (usuario != null) {
                //podemos ver qué acción ejecutó
                //mediante la URL del request
                String urlBase = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                //y los parámetros de query string
                //los que vienen luego de "?" en la url
                String queryString = request.getQueryString();
                //aquí puedes guardar esto en algún lugar
                //log, base de datos, archivo, etc
            }
        }
        //para que continúe el ciclo request/response, llama a la cadena
        //lo que en realidad hace es llamar al siguiente Filter
        //que puede aplicar para este ciclo request/response
        //si no hay más instancias de Filter, entonces se ejecuta el request
        //esto es independiente de si se ejecuta GET, POST, etc
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Intentaré hacerlo con tu ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Disculpa que no brinde ejemplos en código pero puedes usar el **Storage html5** (session o local) para guardar todos los eventos en el cliente y cuando hagas una petición al servidor le envias esa estructura de datos. Así tendras data más completa, tal y como lo pediste en tu pregunta inicialmente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la tomaré en cuenta.